# const not enforced in definition of member function

Tags: c++, constants

I'm wondering why the following code compiles when the definition of the member function does not have the same signature as the declaration (definition is missing const).

```
#include <iostream>

class myClass {
public:
    void myFunc(const int);
};

void myClass::myFunc(int a){
    a += 1;
    std::cout << a << "\n";
}

int main()
{
  myClass myObject;
  myObject.myFunc(5);
}
```

Comment: In a declaration `const int` is the same as `int`. Sure there most be a dupe looking for it.

Comment: Since you are passing by value, the `const` conveys no meaning to the caller - they are indistinguishable, by the guarantees they provide, to the caller.